# PHP Session for counting visits and redirect if (session['visits']=1)

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am trying to make a page on which if you user comes first time it redirects to the index page but if user comes 2nd time the page doesn't redirect.
I am using simple php session for counting the visit and an if statement for checking condition:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views'] = $SESSION['views']+1;
if($SESSION['views'] = 1){
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

The problem is to initialize the array with zero i.e

```
<?php    
$_SESSION['views']=0;
?>
```

It's niether as much simple as it seems and nor much tough.

Comment: you need to add == to the if not =

Comment: You accidentally set your session var to 1. `if($SESSION['views'] = 1)`. Use `==` instead for conditional statements, not `=`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `isset()` to check if the key has been created:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['views'])) { 
    $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+1;

if ($_SESSION['views'] == 1) {
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Also be careful: you had `if ($SESSION['views'] = 1)` which is sets the key to 1 not compares it, and the correct superglobal name is `$_SESSION` not `$SESSION`.

Comment: Thanks nivrig for pointing out my mistake....
Exactly it's the place I should use isset()
Hope it gonna work noW,,,,

Answer (score 1):

first of all (where @nivrig and @Yan dont fix)

```
if($_SESSION['views'] = 1){
header("location:index.php");
}
```

should be

```
if ($_SESSION['views'] == 1){ 
header("location:index.php");
}
```

and go with  @nivrig
his example is right

Answer (score 0):

Agree with nivrig. 
Check if the session has been set.

You have a couple of syntax errors in your code though:

Make sure you write $_SESSION and not $SESSION and when you use an if case you have to use == to compare. A single = will assign a value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to worry about initializing the variable first, utilize [isset()](http://us.php.net/isset) which will check if the variable is set and is not NULL:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
    $_SESSION['views']++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

If you do not care about how many times the user has been to the page, then you could simply use:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['views'])){
    $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The second solution does not worry about increasing the number of `views` and just checks if the value has been set yet or not.  If it hasn't been set, then you can assert that this is the user's first time visiting the page and you would then set the variable and redirect the user.  By setting the variable, you will ensure that the user does not enter a loop after they have already viewed the page.  This approach should better simplify things as initially requested.

Also make sure you put `exit()` after redirecting the user.  This makes sure that any code below does not get executed when redirecting the user.